# What is an effective way to pad a variable length dataset for batching in Tensorflow that does not have have exact

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-datasets

I am trying to integrate the Dataset API into my input pipeline. Before this integration, the program used tf.train.batch_join(), which had dynamic padding enabled. Hence, this would batch elements and pad them according to the largest one in the mini-batch.

```
image, width, label, length, text, filename  = tf.train.batch_join( 
        data_tuples, 
        batch_size=batch_size,
        capacity=queue_capacity,
        allow_smaller_final_batch=final_batch,
        dynamic_pad=True)
```

For dataset, however, I was unable to find the exact alternative to this. I cannot use padded batch, since the dimensions of the images does not have a set threshold. The image width could be anything. My partner and I were able to come up with a work around for this using tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence(). Here is an excerpt:

```
dataset = dataset.apply(tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length
                            (element_length_func=_element_length_fn,
                             bucket_batch_sizes=np.full(len([0]) + 1, batch_size),
                             bucket_boundaries=[0]))
```

What this does is basically dumps all the elements into the overflow bucket since the boundary is set to 0. Then, it batches it from that bucket since bucketing pads the elements according to the largest one.

Is there a better way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: Re: "cannot use padded batch, since the dimensions of the images does not have a set threshold." The `padded_batch()` transformation doesn't require a fixed size for the inputs, and it's what `tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length()` uses [under the covers](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/f202958ee2d5177a474e3d107fdbf0c83174d099/tensorflow/contrib/data/python/ops/grouping.py#L220). Can you describe more about what the shapes of your inputs are, and demonstrate what goes wrong when you try to use `padded_batch()`?

Comment: Ahhh...I think there was a misunderstanding about how padded_batch() works in the first place. Thank you for your input!

Comment: I meet the same problem. What is worse, my input data has two variable length dimensions, so even `tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length()`  can not solve my problem.

Answer (score 2):

I meet exactly the same problem. Now I know how to solve this. If your `input_data` only has one dimension that is of variable length, try to use `tf.contrib.data.bucket_by_sequence_length` to `dataset.apply()` function, make `bucket_batch_sizes = [batch_size] * (len(buckets) + 1)`. And there is another way to do so just as @mrry has said in comments.

```
    iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
    item = iterator.get_next()
    padded_shapes = []
    for i in item:
        padded_shapes.append(i.get_shape())
    padded_shapes = tf.contrib.framework.nest.pack_sequence_as(item, padded_shapes)
    dataset = dataset.padded_batch(batch_size, padded_shapes)
```

If one dimension in the shapes of a tensor is None or -1, then `padded_batch` will pad the tensor on that dimension to max length of the batch.

My training data has two features of varibale length, And this method works fine.